# Sum(30/365) Not Producing Expected Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a better way to calculate my result:

All I want is the Result of 30/365 = 0.0821917808 so I can use this in a further calculating.  When producing this in a script I get zero.  The below is one method to produce the result but there must be a better way.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.  Thanks all.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_DOS_SCORE] (
[SCORE]         [DBO].[EXPCURRENCY] DEFAULT ((0.00)),
[YEAR]          [DBO].[EXPCURRENCY] DEFAULT ((0.00)),
[RESULT]        [DBO].[EXPCURRENCY] DEFAULT ((0.00)),
[LAST_MODIFIED] DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE()) )


INSERT INTO [_DOS_SCORE] (SCORE, YEAR)
VALUES
(30,365),
(60,365)

UPDATE [_DOS_SCORE] SET RESULT = SCORE/YEAR

SELECT * FROM [_DOS_SCORE]
```

Comment: What is `DBO.EXPCURRENCY`?

Comment: Please note creating types like EXPCURRENCY is counter productive in that it hides problems with datatypes and makes code harder to understand (and change).

Comment: +1 @MitchWheat Also they are really hard to change once they are being used. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Numeric data type

```
declare @DOS_SCORE as table (SCORE numeric(18,10) default 0, YEAR numeric(18,10) default 0, RESULT numeric(18,10) default 0,LAST_MODIFIED datetime default getdate())




INSERT INTO @DOS_SCORE (SCORE, YEAR)
VALUES
(30,365),
(60,365)

UPDATE @DOS_SCORE SET RESULT = SCORE/YEAR

SELECT * FROM @DOS_SCORE
```

result is

```
SCORE   YEAR    RESULT  LAST_MODIFIED
30.0000000000   365.0000000000  0.0821917808    2018-10-02 10:36:25.943
60.0000000000   365.0000000000  0.1643835616    2018-10-02 10:36:25.943
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist.  This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: change the data type of your column `RESULT` from type `EXPCURRENCY` to an appropriate `decimal(P, S)` data type . You should carefully choose what `P` and `S` are after reviewing [Microsoft SQL Server documentation on decimal precision, scale, and length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

(Do *not* use `float` unless you understand the implications of using an inexact data type. Currency is *not* a good candidate for any `float` data type.)

Step 2: you may need to perform the calculation as `SELECT 1.0 * SCORE / YEAR`. This will convert any `int` value to `decimal` first (as the result of `int` / `int` is also `int`, truncated).

Step 3: review your data types. `EXPCURRENCY` seems an awfully weird data type for columns named `SCORE` and `YEAR`.

Comment: Agreed, EXPCURRENCY was very weird but I was getting a bit flustered with it.  Thanks for your comments, great pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

One of your arguments has to be a decimal. For example: `SELECT 30.0 / 365` returns `0.082191`.

If you need to store this value in a field/attribute, go with @ErikE and use the `DECIMAL(A,B)` data type.

Comment: Thanks Zack - great tip as I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL fiddle with `Money` instead of `ExpCurrency`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3cf36c/1

```
 - SCORE    YEAR    RESULT  LAST_MODIFIED
 - 30       365     0.0821  2018-10-02T00:27:25.893Z
 - 60       365     0.1643  2018-10-02T00:27:25.893Z
```

Without much information about ExpCurrency, its hard to tell.

Comment: `money` is a terrible data type and should never be used. In many contexts it hides the fact that it has 4 decimal places after the decimal point...

Comment: which datatype do you suggest for currency in sql server

Comment: `decimal(x, 2)` or whatever precision and scale you want. Because even using 4 places of scale will work better as you will always be able to see there are 4 decimal places.

Comment: as per https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp, its saying storage of 5-17 bytes for decimal. and for money is a fixed 8 bytes

Comment: money divided by scalar value (in this case 365) gives result to four precision. dont see anything wrong in this.

Comment: Did I say anything about the problem lying in the resulting precision or scale? I said it's a terrible data type to use, and that is 100% true because many developers are not familiar with it. Depending on how you display it, it can truncate the last 2 decimal places at display time. A developer who codes with `money` without this understanding can introduce *serious* bugs in software that is actually working with money, because of the fractional cent values that *he cannot see*.

Comment: Just to back up @ErikE comments. https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes